# Executing a class method as a Lambda handler

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I'm attempting to use a class method as a Lambda handler within AWS.  I've followed along with the example setup (creating a virtualenv and zipping it up) but I'm not able to get a working call.

My package name is "cloudwatch_metrics" and this is my package init file:

```
from exporter import Exporter
from sns_exporter import SnsExporter
from sqs_exporter import SqsExporter
from elb_exporter import ElbExporter
```

From within the virtualenv that I zipped up and deployed, I can execute the sister "main" function to the lambda handler with:

```
 python -m cloudwatch_metrics.elb_exporter
```

Any suggestions on what syntax I should be using for this?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and added some shim scripts that set up imports and called into the correct function.  Each class got a unique shim file.  As a positive side benefit, that shortened the string name of the handler function and makes it more readable in the AWS Console.